# Reuse X number of prototype beans

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, netty, spring-bean

I'm building an application in spring boot that creates X number of Netty tcp socket servers based on my config.

I would like to have X number of `MyChannelHandler` beans (one for each tcp port). The idea is to have separate worlds/servers in my application and each world has X number of game channels (not related to netty channel). Each game channel is represented by a tcp socket server running on some port.

```
@Component
@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
@Sharable
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyChannelHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

    private final int port;

    @Autowired
    private ContextAwareLogger logger;
    @Autowired
    private AppConfig config;
    @Autowired
    private GameService gameService;
    @Autowired
    private ObjectProvider<GameClient> clientObjectProvider;

    private Map<String, GameClient> connectedClients = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<>());

    @Override
    public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        // logic omitted
    }

    @Override
    public void channelInactive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
       // logic omitted
    }

    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
        // logic omitted
    }

    @Override
    public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        // logic omitted
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable t) throws Exception {
        // logic omitted
    }

    public Map<String, GameClient> getConnectedClients() {
        return connectedClients;
    }

    private GameClient initClient(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
        // logic omitted
    }

}
```

Servers created here:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MySocketServer {

    public static final AttributeKey<Boolean> PACKET_START_KEY = AttributeKey.valueOf("PACKET_START");
    public static final AttributeKey<MyGameClient> CLIENT_ATTRIBUTE_KEY = AttributeKey.valueOf("CLIENT");
    public static final AttributeKey<String> CLIENT_ID_KEY = AttributeKey.valueOf("CLIENT_ID_KEY");
    public static final AttributeKey<Boolean> HANDSHAKE_KEY = AttributeKey.valueOf("HANDSHAKE");


    private final ContextAwareLogger logger;
    private final AppConfig config;
    private final ObjectProvider<MyGameClient> clientObjectProvider;

    @Qualifier("MyServerInitializer")
    @Autowired
    private ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> serverInitializer;
    @Qualifier("MyChannelInitializer")
    @Autowired
    private ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> channelInitializer;

    @Qualifier("serverBossGroup")
    @Autowired
    private NioEventLoopGroup bossGroup;

    @Qualifier("serverWorkerGroup")
    @Autowired
    private NioEventLoopGroup workerGroup;

    private Channel loginChannel;
    private List<Channel> worldChannels = new ArrayList<>();

    @PostConstruct
    public void start() {
        try {
            ServerBootstrap bootstrap = init(serverInitializer);
            loginChannel = bootstrap.bind(config.getServer().getSocketServerPort()).sync().channel(); // save the main channel so we can cleanly close it when app is shutdown
            logger.info("Netty server started...");

            initWorlds();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void stop() throws InterruptedException {
        logger.info("Shutting down Netty server");
        bossGroup.shutdownGracefully().sync();
        workerGroup.shutdownGracefully().sync();
        loginChannel.closeFuture().sync();
        logger.info("Netty Server shutdown complete.");
    }

    private ServerBootstrap init(ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> initializer) {
        return new ServerBootstrap()
                .group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
                .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 5000) // todo: get from config
                //.attr(PACKET_START_ATTRIBUTE_KEY, true) // didnt work for some reason
                .childHandler(initializer);
    }

    // each world has X numberOfChannels
    private void initWorlds() throws InterruptedException {
        List<WorldConfig> activeWorlds = config.getWorlds().stream()
                .filter(w -> w.getActive() == 1)
                .toList();

        for (int i = 0; i < activeWorlds.size(); i++) {
            logger.info("Starting world: " + i);
            int startPort = config.getServer().getChannelPort() + i * 100; // 7575, 7675, etc
            for (int j = startPort; j < startPort + activeWorlds.get(i).getNumberOfChannels(); j++) {
                logger.info("Starting channel on port: " + j);
                ServerBootstrap bootstrap = init(channelInitializer);
                worldChannels.add(bootstrap.bind(j).sync().channel());
                logger.info("Channel started successfully");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Initializer that will create the channel pipeline (The initChannel is called for each inbound client that connects)

```
@Component
@Qualifier("MyChannelInitializer")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyChannelInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> {

    private final MyPacketDecoder myPacketDecoder;
    //private final MyChannelHandler myChannelHandler;
    private final MyPacketEncoder myPacketEncoder;
    private final DefaultEventExecutorGroup eventExecutorGroup;

    private final BeanFactory beanFactory;
    private final ObjectProvider<MyChannelHandler> provider;

    /**
     * This creates the pipeline for every new channel created (every new client connection)
     * Inbound is handled top down (myPacketDecoder->myChannelHandler)
     * Outboud is handled bottom up (myPacketEncoder)
     *
     *
     * @param socketChannel
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Override
    protected void initChannel(SocketChannel socketChannel) throws Exception {
        int port = socketChannel.localAddress().getPort();
        MyChannelHandler myChannelHandler = provider.getObject(port);
        MyChannelHandler myChannelHandler2 = provider.getObject(port); // this object should be the same as myChannelHandler
        socketChannel.pipeline()
                .addLast(eventExecutorGroup, "decoder", myPacketDecoder) // inbound
                .addLast("encoder", myPacketEncoder) // outbound
                .addLast(eventExecutorGroup, "inbound", myChannelHandler); // inbound
    }

}
```

Example scenario..
config:

```
config:
  server: # properties that apply to the whole server
    socketServerPort: 8484 # login port
    channelPort: 7575 # channels start
    worlds: # configs per world
      - 
        active: 1
        numberOfChannels: 5
      - 
        active: 1
        numberOfChannels: 3
      - 
        active: 0
        numberOfChannels: 3
```

My server will start up login server followed by 2 worlds with 5 and 3 channels respectively

login server: 8484
world 1 channel 1: 7575
world 1 channel 2: 7576
world 1 channel 3: 7577
world 1 channel 4: 7578
world 1 channel 5: 7579
world 2 channel 1: 7675
world 2 channel 2: 7676
world 2 channel 3: 7677

client 1 connects to 7575, initChannel() should use instance of `MyChannelHandler`. However, because of the prototype definition, each call to `provider.getObject(port)` is returning a new instance. How can I get it to return and reuse the same instance for the same port?

The above scenarios should have 8 `MyChannelHandler` beans.
Maybe I can use some factory pattern to inject the 8 beans into a map and then access the map on the initChannel?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by removing these two annotations from my handler class

```
@Component
@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
```

I autowired `GenericApplicationContext context` inside my SocketServer class so I could register bean definition manually during my initWorlds logic:

```
for (int j = startPort; j < startPort + activeWorlds.get(i).getNumberOfChannels(); j++) {
                logger.info("Starting channel on port: " + j);
                context.registerBean(String.valueOf(j), MapleChannelHandler.class, createChannelHandler(j));
                ServerBootstrap bootstrap = init(channelInitializer);
                worldChannels.add(bootstrap.bind(j).sync().channel());
                logger.info("Channel started successfully");
            }
```

```
private Supplier<MapleChannelHandler> createChannlerHandler(int port) {
        return () -> new MapleChannelHandler(port);
    }
```

Now my initChannel is simple:

```
    @Override
    protected void initChannel(SocketChannel socketChannel) throws Exception {
        int port = socketChannel.localAddress().getPort();
        MapleChannelHandler mapleChannelHandler = beanFactory.getBean(String.valueOf(port), MapleChannelHandler.class);
        socketChannel.pipeline()
                .addLast(eventExecutorGroup, "decoder", maplePacketDecoder) // inbound
                .addLast("encoder", maplePacketEncoder) // outbound
                .addLast(eventExecutorGroup, "inbound", mapleChannelHandler); // inbound
   }
```

Now whenever a client connects on port X, it will use the bean that was registered with name of port X